# How to make circle by using HTML CSS only?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have above image and i want to make this circle structure with HTML CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
   width: 96px;
   height: 96px;
   background: #eee;
   border-color: red;
   border-style: solid;
   border-radius: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
```

Please help me to create inner structure of Circle like above image by using HTML CSS, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yin Yang - https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Good Job @Harry :)

Comment: Thank You so much @Harry :)

Comment: @Harry, you should add this as an answer!

Comment: @KarlGjertsen: Felt odd because it wasn't my code and is readily available on the net.

Comment: @Harry, you can paste the HTML and put a link to where you got it from.

Comment: Ah, ok @KarlGjertsen Another user has already done that (without attribution though) and so I'll leave it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```css
#yin-yang { 
  width: 96px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #eee; 
  border-color: red; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 2px 2px 50px 2px; 
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#yin-yang:before { 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 18px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
} 

#yin-yang:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
  border: 18px solid #eee;
  border-radius:100%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yin-yang"></div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you indicate your source.